# Calling a function before it is declared

Tags: php

The following code runs in PHP

```php
<?php

$foo = "Chocolate milkshake";

go($foo);

function go($param) {
    echo $param;
}

?>

// Output: chocolate milkshake
```

See this **Demo** http://codepad.viper-7.com/ToApZa

This code runs without errors and prints specified output, why?
I thought this "function hoisting" only occurred in JavaScript

Comment: PHP isn't interpreted line-wise. The parser does prepare a function declaration table. They need to be declared in a scripts outermost global code block though. Deferred and nested functions aren't picked up as such.

Comment: I wondered if that was the case - made a little test [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8pqSgG) - thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you declare your functions in PHP in most cases, as you've just proved :)

Take a look at [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) for more details. The key point:

> Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, except when a function is conditionally defined as shown in the two examples below.

Comment: thanks, that page suggests that the nesting issue also applies to block scope too